# saber porcentaje en javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy haciendo una barra de progreso que según una cuenta atrás, ciera la sesión automáticamente según el tiempo pasado.

Este es el ejemplo de como funciona mas o menos. Faltaria el aviso de que se va a cerrar la sesión, pero por lo demás es así.

```js
//tiempo de sesion
var Temporizador=18000;
var TiempoSesion=setInterval(timer, 1000); //1000 will  run it every 1 second

function timer() {
Temporizador=Temporizador-1;
if (Temporizador == 18000) { $("#Avatar").removeClass(); $("#Avatar").addClass( "avatar-container p-100");}
if (Temporizador == 12000) { $("#Avatar").removeClass(); $("#Avatar").addClass( "avatar-container p-80"); }
if (Temporizador == 6000) { $("#Avatar").removeClass(); $("#Avatar").addClass( "avatar-container p-60"); }
if (Temporizador == 3000) { $("#Avatar").removeClass(); $("#Avatar").addClass( "avatar-container p-50"); }
if (Temporizador == 2400) { $("#Avatar").removeClass(); $("#Avatar").addClass( "avatar-container p-40"); }
if (Temporizador == 1800) { $("#Avatar").removeClass(); $("#Avatar").addClass( "avatar-container p-30"); }
if (Temporizador == 1200) { $("#Avatar").removeClass(); $("#Avatar").addClass( "avatar-container p-20"); }
if (Temporizador == 600) { $("#Avatar").removeClass(); $("#Avatar").addClass( "avatar-container p-10"); Alerta('<strong class="TituloAviso">¡TU SESIÓN SE VA A CERRAR!</strong><p style="font-size: 14px; margin-top:10px;">Solo faltan <span id="timer" style="display: inline;font-size: 16px;font-style: bold">60</span> segundos.</p><p style="margin-top:10px; font-size: 14px;">¿Quieres mantenerla abierta?</p><p style="margin-left: 20px; margin-top: 20px;"><a style="text-decoration: none; padding: 4px 30px 3px 30px; border-radius: 4px;" href="javascript:;" onclick="resetTimer()" class="botonverde" data-spop="close" aria-hidden="true">Si</a><a style="margin-left: 20px; text-decoration: none; padding: 4px 30px 3px 30px; border-radius: 4px;" href="Salir.php" class="botonrojo" aria-hidden="true">No</a></p>','notice',60000);
}
if (Temporizador <= 0) {
   location.href = 'Salir.php';
     clearInterval(TiempoSesion); //counter ended, do something here
     return;
  }
$('#timer').html(Temporizador);
   document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML=Temporizador + " Segundos"; // watch for spelling
}
```

```css
.avatar-container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 130px;
  width: 130px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 1rem;
  border: none;
  background: #efefef;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.avatar-container .avatar {
  display: block;
  margin: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 100;
}
.avatar-container .avatar img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}



.p-1 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(93.6deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-2 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(97.2deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-3 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(100.8deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-4 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(104.4deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-5 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(108deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-6 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(111.6deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-7 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(115.2deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-8 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(118.8deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-9 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(122.4deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-10 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(126deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-11 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(129.6deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-12 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(133.2deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-13 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(136.8deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-14 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(140.4deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-15 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(144deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-16 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(147.6deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-17 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(151.2deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-18 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(154.8deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-19 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(158.4deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-20 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(162deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-21 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(165.6deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-22 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(169.2deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-23 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(172.8deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-24 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(176.4deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-25 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(180deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-26 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(183.6deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-27 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(187.2deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-28 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(190.8deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-29 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(194.4deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-30 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(198deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-31 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(201.6deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-32 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(205.2deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-33 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(208.8deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-34 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(212.4deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-35 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(216deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-36 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(219.6deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-37 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(223.2deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-38 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(226.8deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-39 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(230.4deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-40 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(234deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-41 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(237.6deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-42 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(241.2deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-43 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(244.8deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-44 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(248.4deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-45 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(252deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-46 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(255.6deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-47 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(259.2deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-48 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(262.8deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-49 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(266.4deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-50 { background-image: linear-gradient(-90deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-51 { background-image: linear-gradient(-86.4deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-52 { background-image: linear-gradient(-82.8deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-53 { background-image: linear-gradient(-79.2deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-54 { background-image: linear-gradient(-75.6deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-55 { background-image: linear-gradient(-72deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-56 { background-image: linear-gradient(-68.4deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-57 { background-image: linear-gradient(-64.8deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-58 { background-image: linear-gradient(-61.2deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-59 { background-image: linear-gradient(-57.6deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-60 { background-image: linear-gradient(-54deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-61 { background-image: linear-gradient(-50.4deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-62 { background-image: linear-gradient(-46.8deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-63 { background-image: linear-gradient(-43.2deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-64 { background-image: linear-gradient(-39.6deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-65 { background-image: linear-gradient(-36deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-66 { background-image: linear-gradient(-32.4deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-67 { background-image: linear-gradient(-28.8deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-68 { background-image: linear-gradient(-25.2deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-69 { background-image: linear-gradient(-21.6deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-70 { background-image: linear-gradient(-18deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-71 { background-image: linear-gradient(-14.4deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-72 { background-image: linear-gradient(-10.8deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-73 { background-image: linear-gradient(-7.2deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-74 { background-image: linear-gradient(-3.6deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-75 { background-image: linear-gradient(0deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-76 { background-image: linear-gradient(3.6deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-77 { background-image: linear-gradient(7.2deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-78 { background-image: linear-gradient(10.8deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-79 { background-image: linear-gradient(14.4deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-80 { background-image: linear-gradient(18deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-81 { background-image: linear-gradient(21.6deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-82 { background-image: linear-gradient(25.2deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-83 { background-image: linear-gradient(28.8deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-84 { background-image: linear-gradient(32.4deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-85 { background-image: linear-gradient(36deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-86 { background-image: linear-gradient(39.6deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-87 { background-image: linear-gradient(43.2deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-88 { background-image: linear-gradient(46.8deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-89 { background-image: linear-gradient(50.4deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-90 { background-image: linear-gradient(54deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-91 { background-image: linear-gradient(57.6deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-92 { background-image: linear-gradient(61.2deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-93 { background-image: linear-gradient(64.8deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-94 { background-image: linear-gradient(68.4deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-95 { background-image: linear-gradient(72deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-96 { background-image: linear-gradient(75.6deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-97 { background-image: linear-gradient(79.2deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-98 { background-image: linear-gradient(82.8deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-99 { background-image: linear-gradient(86.4deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-100 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="Avatar" class="avatar-container p-100">
  <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/_shahedk/128.jpg"  class="avatar"/>
</div><!--.avatar-container-->

<span id="timer"></span>
```

Si os fijáis en vez de usar el porcentaje lo que hago es mover la barra de progreso según tiempos, pero no me convence.

¿Hay alguna manera de saber el porcentaje del tiempo que llevo recorrido? Osea que la idea es quitar los tiempos fijos y poner el porcentaje en su lugar

Comment: para el porcentaje seria `100* (segundosMaximos -segundosRestantes) / segundosMaximos` no?

Comment: Lo único que tienes que hacer es una regla de 3. porcentaje=tiempoCadaActualizacion/tiempoTotalFinal*100;
tiempoCadaActualizacion+=incremento;
y poner eso en un setInterval.

Comment: @abrahamhs ¿que es tiempoCadaActualizacion? una variable nueva o un segundo?

Comment: @lois6b estoy probando pero no tengo muy clara la sintaxis... sabrias cual es?

Comment: tiempoCadaActualizacion= seria algo asi como lo que puso lois6b segundosRestantes, pero eso va de la mano con lo que pongas en un setInterval.

Answer (score 0):

Por si a alguien le vale.

la solución ha sido declarar una variable con el tiempo total y luego poner esto:

```
var Porcentaje = ((Temporizador/tiempoTotalFinal)*100).toFixed(0);
```